# Drawing instances with WebGL2 - vertexAttribDivisor

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I'm learning webgl2 from https://webgl2fundamentals.org. I'm learning about [instancing](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html) right now. I can get the demo to work, where it draws many crosses, and I can get it to work with 500 instances.

But I cannot add anything else to the scene. I have a simple triangle that renders fine without the instancing, but with the crosses added the triangle disappears. I believe it has to do with gl.vertexAttribDivisor. I'm not sure when I need to call it, or if I need to undo it somehow.

If I omit calls to vertexAttribDivisor, the crosses don't render correctly, but the triangle is fine. If I replace the call to vertexAttribDivisor, the triangle disappears.

When do I call gl.vertexAttribDivisor? Do I have to undo the call to resume normal, non-instanced rendering? What does it really do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex attribute functions change a single global state. [vertexAttribDivisor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/vertexAttribDivisor) sets the divisor for a specified *generic* vertex attribute (one of the globally available ones), for every `draw*` call you want to setup the attributes using `vertexAttribPointer` and `vertexAttribDivisor`, if you changed the divisor for an attribute for one draw call but don't want to use the same divisor for your following draw call you need to reset it.

Comment: vertexAttribDivisor is set per attribute on a shader, right? If I enable a new shader with its own attributes, do I have to reset the divisor back to zero? I would assume no, but my program doesn't work until I do.

Comment: I did some testing. My instanced test object's position attribute number was the same as one of the attribute numbers for my non-instanced object. Once I forced those to change then I no longer have to reset the divisor. Does this mean the vertexAttribDivisor is set set per attribute number regardless of the program that's active?

Comment: Attributes are global and not tied to programs